# Write XHR data with line break

Tags: php, jquery, newline, fwrite

I get some data from a variable, and send it via XHR to PHP file which write it in to a file.
How can I make a line break in the file after every write to it?

```
var e='Hello world!'
$.getJSON('http://example.com/write.php?callback=&data='+e);
```

**write.php:**

```
$data = $_GET['data'];
if(!$op=fopen('my file name','ab')){
  $res='b';
  exit;
}
if(fwrite($op,$data)===FALSE){
  $res='b';
  exit;
}
fclose($op);
```

Comment: Write a [`PHP_EOL`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)?

Comment: @Daedalus I do not what happened with the \ n

Comment: @Aleksov I don't know what you mean.. just append the string `\n` to the end of your data.  That's a line break.  No space between the backward slash and the n.

Comment: @Aleksov, please try `fwrite($op, PHP_EOL)` after your previous `fwrite`

Comment: @Daedalus It did not work for me. Data written to the file is still in one line. Maybe I did not put it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing or appending a [`PHP_EOL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) to the file after you have written your data.

```
fwrite($op, PHP_EOL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$data = $_GET['data'];

if(!$op=fopen('my file name','ab')){
  $res='b';
  exit;
}
if(fwrite($op,$data . PHP_EOL)===FALSE){
  $res='b';
  exit;
}
fclose($op);
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, fwrite() will automatically append a newline for each write.

Are you running PHP on a Windows server? You might try to open the file to write to in 'at' mode (append, translate line-endings) in stead of 'binary' mode (ab);

$op = fopen('my file name','at');

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php